# Angular UIRouter not changing with child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UIRouter and have the following states set up:

```
$stateProvider.state('forgot-password', {
        url: '/forgot-password',
        component: 'forgotPassword'
})
.state('forgot-password.reset', {
        url: '/:token',
        component: 'forgotPasswordReset'
});
```

When I navigate to `/forgot-password` I get the correct view however when I navigate to `/forgot-password/abc` I still get directed to `forgotPassword`. How do I get the router to send me to the `forgot-password.reset` state?

Comment: add url like `url : '/reset/:token'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few different reasons why this might be happening. Just off the top of my head:

- You don't have a `ui-view` directive in the template for your `forgotPassword` component.
- One or both of the components aren't registered (but you should see console errors thrown if this is the case).
- You're hitting the wrong URL to try to activate the state.
- Some other state is being activated for some unknown reason. Maybe you've set up a `redirectTo` rule on a state somewhere, or you're doing it from your controller.

UI Router is quite large and can get unwieldy if you're not careful, so it's hard to give too detailed of an answer without knowing your project. Please give some more details if any of the above suggestions don't work.

Comment: Ah thanks for this, I realized that it was the `ui-view` missing